# Ionic - how to cast any to string

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this piece of code... I am trying to pass a string to another page:

```
  constructor(public router : Router) {
    if (router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      this.statusIcon = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
    }
  }
```

Since from another page I pass this :

```
  pushImageAsParams(pageUrl : any, params : any) {
    this.nav.navigateForward(pageUrl, {state : params});
  }
```

how I can cast from any to string?
Practically I am trying to change img src in home.page.ts from another page during a refresh state....

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: your question is lacking details in order to answer it correctly, if you log the current content of the `params` variable what does it show you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **as** operator or simply use **toString()** function

```
  constructor(public router : Router) {
    if (router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      this.statusIcon = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.toString();
    }
  }
```